# CABasicAnimation - transform scale keep in center

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics, mask, catransform3d

Trying to animatie an ellipse masked on a UIView to be scale transformed remaining in the center position.

I have found [CALayer - CABasicAnimation not scaling around center/anchorPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495956/calayer-cabasicanimation-not-scaling-around-center-anchorpoint), and followed by adding a `bounds` property to the `maskLayer` `CAShapeLayer` however, this ends with the mask being positioned in the left corner with only 1/4 of it showing. I would like the mask to remain within the center of the screen.

```
@synthesize maskedView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Next"];

    vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
vc.view.layer.bounds = self.view.layer.bounds;

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

    CGRect maskRect = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-50, (self.view.frame.size.height/2)-50, 100, 100);
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, nil, maskRect);
    [maskLayer setPath:path];

    CGPathRelease(path);

    vc.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];

    maskedView = vc.view;
    [self startAnimation];
}
```

Animation...

```
-(void)startAnimation
{
    maskedView.layer.mask.bounds = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-50, (self.view.frame.size.height/2)-50, 100, 100);
    maskedView.layer.mask.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5,.5);
    maskedView.layer.mask.contentsGravity = @"center";

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];

    animation.duration = 1.0f;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f];

    [maskedView.layer.mask addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateMask"];
}
```

---

**Update**

I seem to have fixed this with a second animation on the `position` key. Is this correct or is there a better way of doing this?

```
CABasicAnimation *animation2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

animation2.duration = 1.0f;

animation2.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

animation2.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2), (self.view.frame.size.height/2))];
animation2.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2), (self.view.frame.size.height/2))];

[toBeMask.layer.mask addAnimation:animation2 forKey:@"animateMask2"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seem to have fixed this with a second animation on the position key. Is this correct or is there a better way of doing this?

```
CABasicAnimation *animation2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

animation2.duration = 1.0f;

animation2.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

animation2.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2), (self.view.frame.size.height/2))];
animation2.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2), (self.view.frame.size.height/2))];

[toBeMask.layer.mask addAnimation:animation2 forKey:@"animateMask2"];
```

Comment: It's better to fix the scale animation to scale about the correct point, instead of doing two animations to hide the incorrectness of the first animation. A lot less code, for one thing.

Answer (score 23):

You can create a scale around the center of the object instead of (0, 0) like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *scale = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
CATransform3D tr = CATransform3DIdentity;
tr = CATransform3DTranslate(tr, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2, 0);
tr = CATransform3DScale(tr, 3, 3, 1);
tr = CATransform3DTranslate(tr, -self.bounds.size.width/2, -self.bounds.size.height/2, 0);
scale.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:tr];
```

So we start out with the "identity" transform (which means 'no transform'). Then we translate (move) to the center of the object. Then we scale. Then we move back to origo so we're back where we started (we only wanted to affect the scale operation).

Comment: Doesn't the scaling affect the translation you do after it? I'm testing this (as well as with normal affine transform) and the view always ends top left far away from it's initial position.

Comment: This one was worked in my case
   `CABasicAnimation *scale = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
CATransform3D tr = CATransform3DIdentity;
tr = CATransform3DScale(tr, 3, 3, 1);
scale.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:tr];`

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure why, but CAShapeLayer does not set the bounds property to the layer. In my case, that's was the problem.
Try setting the bounds. That should work.

*I did something like this for building the initial circle*

```
self.circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
CGRect roundedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width);
self.circle.bounds = roundedRect;
UIBezierPath *start = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedRect cornerRadius:width/2];
[self.circle setPath:start.CGPath];
self.circle.position = CGPointMake(whatever suits you);
self.circleView.layer.mask = self.circle;
[self.circleView.layer.mask setValue: @(1) forKeyPath: @"transform.scale"];
```

*And something like this for scaling it*

```
CABasicAnimation *scale = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
scale.fromValue = [self.circleView.layer.mask valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
scale.toValue = @(100);
scale.duration = 1.0;
scale.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[self.circleView.layer.mask setValue:scale.toValue forKeyPath:scale.keyPath];
[self.circleView.layer.mask addAnimation:scale forKey:scale.keyPath];
```

PD: AnchorPoint is by default (.5,.5) according to apple documentations...but we all know that does not mean anything right?

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 5):

I have written following function with many added tweaks and options, could be useful for many others.

```
func layerScaleAnimation(layer: CALayer, duration: CFTimeInterval, fromValue: CGFloat, toValue: CGFloat) {
    let timing = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
    let scaleAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(timing)
    scaleAnimation.duration = duration
    scaleAnimation.fromValue = fromValue
    scaleAnimation.toValue = toValue
    layer.add(scaleAnimation, forKey: "scale")
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to update size after animation completion, because CATransaction reverts back to actual size.

Comment: scrubber? ,.,./,.

Comment: guess scrubber is supposed to be layer? anywas. helped me pretty well. thank you >)

Comment: @DavidSeek yes its layer not scrubber, I have updated my answer thanks.