# Border Layer animation not Scaling from Center

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, calayer

I am struggling with the strange issue like when I am adding scale transformation to any layer, it doesn't animated from the center. It does from origin.

```
func addSquareBorderLayer() {

    borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let rect = CGRect(x: spotlight!.frame.origin.x, y: spotlight!.frame.origin.y, width: spotlight!.frame.width, height: spotlight!.frame.height)
    borderLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: spotlight!.cornerRadius).cgPath
    borderLayer?.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 91/255, green: 186/255, blue: 162/255, alpha: 1).cgColor //ColorRGB(91, 186, 162)
    borderLayer?.lineWidth = spotlight!.cornerRadius
    borderLayer?.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    layer.addSublayer(borderLayer!)

    animatePulsatingLayer(pulsatingLayer: layer)
}

private func animatePulsatingLayer(pulsatingLayer : CALayer) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    animation.duration       = 0.5
    animation.repeatCount    = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    animation.autoreverses   = true
    animation.fromValue      = 1
    animation.toValue        = 1.05
    pulsatingLayer.add(animation, forKey: "pulsing")
}
```

Can anybody please help?

Refernce to what's happening: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0hqdrrv310du7vz/mo.mov?dl=0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CALayer - CABasicAnimation not scaling around center/anchorPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495956/calayer-cabasicanimation-not-scaling-around-center-anchorpoint). Set the `bounds` of your CAShapeLayer to something nonzero, like a rect with origin zero and size `spotlight.frame.size`.

Comment: @KurtRevis I have tried all the possible solution on SO. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky. You need to set the `frame` for the layer as the `rect` you are setting currently for `path`. And set path `origin` to zero so that the circle(or any shape) is drawn at the same position as frame's origin. This will allow the animation to be applied at the `anchorPoint` (0.5, 0.5).

Here is the complete example,

```
var borderLayer: CAShapeLayer!

func addSquareBorderLayer() {

    let size: CGFloat = 100

    borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: size, height: size))
    borderLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
    borderLayer?.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 91/255, green: 186/255, blue: 162/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    borderLayer?.lineWidth = 20
    borderLayer?.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    borderLayer?.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200), size: rect.size)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer!)

    animatePulsatingLayer(pulsatingLayer: borderLayer!)
}

private func animatePulsatingLayer(pulsatingLayer : CALayer) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    animation.duration       = 0.3
    animation.repeatCount    = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    animation.autoreverses   = true
    animation.fromValue      = 1
    animation.toValue        = 1.2
    pulsatingLayer.add(animation, forKey: "pulsing")
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Can you pls say it will work for Square or Rectangle?

Comment: Yes, animation will work for any kind of shape means it will animate it from the center.